# Search string with regular expression SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

The regex I want to use is: `^(?=.*[,])(,?)ABC(,?)$`

What I want to get out is:

```
^                // start
(?=.*[,])        // contains at least one comma (,)
(,?)ABC(,?)      // The comma is either in the beginning or in the end of the string "ABC"
$                // end
```

Of course `ABC` is ought to be a variable based on my search term.

So if `ABC = 'abc'` then `",abc"`, `"abc,"`, `",abc,"` will match but not `"abc"` or `"abcd"`

Better way to do this is also welcome.

The value in the record looks like `"abc,def,ghi,ab,cde..."` and I need to find out if it contains my element (i.e. `'abc'`). I cannot change the data structure. We can assume that in no case the record will contain only one sub-value, so it is correct to assume that there always is a comma in the value.

Comment: So you wish to search for a `term` in a string having comma separated terms ?

Comment: Yes basically the regex tells it all. It must have one comma either in the beginning or end to make sure my string is not substring of other string, and it will match if it's first string or last as well.

Comment: how about splitting the string with comma delimiter then search after splitting?

Comment: What you currently have is correct. Just don't use `^` and `$`. Use only `(,?)(ABC)(,?)` and capture the second group by using `$2` or `\2` whatever is compatible with `sql-server`. Or by using _non capturing groups_ [like this](https://regex101.com/r/lD3bH1/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if a comma delimited string contains `abc`, then I think `like` is the easiest method in any database:

```
where ',' + col + ',' like '%,abc,%'
```

Comment: That will not match "`abc,def`"

Comment: "abc" could be the first or last item

Comment: @Ddan . . . Of course this will.  That is why commas are pre- and post-pended before the `like`.